# Appcelerator app crash after taking picture

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

My app crashes after taking a picture with the camera.
This has never happened before Using titanium SDK 6.3.0 on iOS 11.
Does anyone have a solution?
thanks

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
                        success: function(event) {
                            lObjPhoto = event.media;            
                            parameters.callbackApply(lObjPhoto);                
                        },
                        cancel: function() {
                            lObjPhoto = null;
                            lObjThumb = null;
                            parameters.callbackApply(lObjPhoto);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                                lObjPhoto = null;
                                var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera', ok: 'Ok'});
                                if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) a.setMessage('Device does not have camera');
                                else a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
                                a.show();
                                parameters.callbackApply(lObjPhoto);        
                        },
                        allowImageEditing: false,
                        saveToPhotoGallery: false,
                    })
```

Comment: Please add sample code to this post showing the problem.  This help article can explain how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have also faced this issue but it's device & Android OS specific. I faced it on Nokia 5 & 6 both on Android 7.1.2. But other devices works fine. So can you add detail info like device name, Android OS version, etc.

Comment: i've added the part of code that i'm using when i call IOS camera

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using these properties in tiapp.xml: NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription.

```
    <ios>
        ...
        <plist>
            <dict>
                ...
                <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Gallery permissions required</string>
                <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
                <string>Camera permissions required</string>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
```

Comment: Are you having this problem on a real device or in emulator?

Comment: on a real device witch xcode i can't emulate the camera

Answer (score 0):

Also use the below code for Marshmallow and above to accept permission

```
var permissions = ['android.permission.CAMERA', 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'];
Ti.Android.requestPermissions(permissions, function(e) {
if (e.success) {
   //Action
   Ti.API.info("Success");

  });
} else {
    Ti.API.info("ERROR: " + e.error);
}
```

});